# How to remove a certain node from a linked list by the data its holding?

Tags: c++

We are suppose to enter a string, and then find where the string is in the linked list and remove that node

when i insert to the front of the list, so i enter data values a, b, c , d, when i print it it comes up as d,c,b,a. Now i insert to the rear of it, entering f and g, and the list now looks, d,c,b,a,f,g. I want to remove f but it just use the remove function it does not and still output the same list

```
using namespace std;

struct node {
    string data;
    node* next;


};

node* addFront(node* s);
node* addRear(node* s);
void remove(node* head, string abc);
void print(node* head);
int main() {
    node* head = NULL;



    cout << "Enter 5 data strings\n";
    cout << "This will be inserted from the back\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        head = addFront(head);

    }
    print(head);
    cout << "Enter 3 strings and this will be inserted from the back of the orignal string\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        head = addRear(head);
    }
    print(head);
    cout << "Removing the head node\n";
    string n;
    cout << "Enter a string to remove\n";
    cin >> n;
    remove(head, n);
    print(head);
}
node* addFront(node* s)
{
    node* person = new node;
    cin >> person->data;
    person->next = s;
    s = person;

    return s;

}
node *addRear(node*s ) {
    node* person = new node;
    cin >> person->data;
    person->next = NULL;
    if (s == NULL) {
        return person;
    }
    else {
        node* last = s;
        while (last->next != NULL) {
            last = last->next;

        }
        last->next = person;
    }
    return s;



}
void remove(node* head, string a) {

    node* previous = NULL;
    node* current = head;
    if (current == NULL) {
        cout << "Value cannot be found\n";
        return;
    }
    else {
        while (previous != NULL) {
            if (current->data == a) {
                previous->next = current->next;
                delete current;
                break;
            }
            current = current->next;
        }
    }

}
void print(node * head)
{
    node* temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL) // don't access ->next
    {
        cout << temp->data << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Is something preventing you from just using std::list and causing you to need your own linked list implementation?

Comment: Your `remove` function does not work if `head` is removed since you never updated `head`.  Time to use the debugger.

Comment: Oh, its because im new to data structures, and our professor wants us to implement it using a linked list

Answer (score 0):

In remove function, previous is most certainly NULL when you hit that while loop.

Perhaps consider a do-while loop instead (with better handling of previous).

You may be better off handling the first node in a different manner since the holder of its previous is essentially the root pointer.

Comment: its still not removing it, and I am not sure why